# Obj C: How to scale only to up?

Tags: objective-c

Hey everbody. I have a little issue here. I just want to scale my view, but only to up. I mean, i dont want it move out from original coords, i just want to scale in one direction, without affecting the position.

```
[UIView beginAnimations: @"myViewAnimation" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];


    redView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 3.0);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Origin of all UIView transforms is its layer's anchorPoint, which is in the center of the view by default. Set anchorPoint to CGPointZero so view will be scaled to the right and upwards and its current position will be fixed:

```
redView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
...

UIView beginAnimations: @"myViewAnimation" context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];

redView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 3.0);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Note also that view's frame is calculated using its layer's anchorPoint so you may need to also adjust your view's frame accordingly

To access view's layer you will need to add `QuartzCore.framework` to link with your project and import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` header file.

Comment: Hey, i understand. But its giving me a error 'Acessing unknown 'anchorPoint' component of a property.'